# richfaces suggestionBox passing additional values to backing bean

Tags: java, jsf, richfaces

When using the RichFaces `suggestionBox` how can you pass more than one id or value from the page with the text input to the `suggestionBox` backing bean.  ie: to show a list of suggested cities within a selected state?  Here is my `autoComplete` method.

```
public List< Suburb > autocomplete(Object suggest)
{
    String pref = (String) suggest;
    ArrayList< Suburb > result = new ArrayList< Suburb >();

    Iterator< Suburb > iterator = getSuburbs().iterator();
    while( iterator.hasNext() )
    {
        Suburb elem = ((Suburb) iterator.next());
        if( (elem.getName() != null && elem.getName().toLowerCase().indexOf( pref.toLowerCase() ) == 0) || "".equals( pref ) )
        {
            result.add( elem );
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

As you can see there is one value passed from the page, `Object` suggest, which is the text of the `h:inputText` (in the faceLets `m:textFormRow`)

```xml
<m:textFormRow id="suburb" label="#{msgs.suburbPrompt}" 
    property="#{bean[dto].addressDTO.suburb}"
    required="true" maxlength="100" size="30" />

<rich:suggestionbox height="200" width="200" usingSuggestObjects="true"
    suggestionAction="#{suburbsMBean.autocomplete}" var="suburb" for="suburb"
    fetchValue="#{suburb.name}" id="suggestion">
    <h:column>
        <h:outputText value="#{suburb.name}" />
    </h:column>
</rich:suggestionbox>
```

Earlier in the page you can select a state which I'd like to use to pare down the list of suburbs that the suggestion box displays.

Comment: You may have to be more explicit about what you are trying to do - for example, posting a simple form with the controls you want to use and spelling out the sequence of events as the user inputs data.

Comment: So you want to select the state, then the suggestionbox would only suggest suburbs from that state ? What does code to select the state look like ?

Answer (score 3):

(Disclaimer: I'm aware that the question was asked rather long time ago, but maybe this'll help someone with a similar problem...)

Check out this blog post which deals with something similar: **[RichFaces - SuggestionBox and hidden field](http://workflow.imixs.org/roller/ralphsjavablog/entry/richfaces_suggestionbox_and_hidden_field)**.

The key is to use `<f:setPropertyActionListener value="#{...}" target="#{...}">` wrapped inside `<a4j:support event="onselect" ajaxSingle="true">`. This can be used to set an additional value for a backing bean when `onselect` is triggered for the SuggestionBox.

With this approach I managed to create a SuggestionBox that displays (and autocompletes) customers' *names* but upon selection sets a whole *customer object* (with several properties; identified by an id) for a bean.

Comment: Here's another SO answer about basically the same problem: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1681559/richfaces-suggestionbox/1687031#1687031

Answer (score 1):

Does using `<f:parameter` tag inside the `<rich:suggestionbox` work?

Comment: although this pointed me in the right direction, it's not an answer. It does contain useful information, though

Answer (score 0):

Have you looked at this RichFaces suggestionBox [demo](http://livedemo.exadel.com/richfaces-demo/richfaces/suggestionBox.jsf?c=suggestionBox&tab=usage) yet ? There are links under the examples to view the source.

Edit:

Sounds like you need the value of state in your bean before the user types in the suggestionBox.  I would use the RichFaces ajax support to pass the value of state to the bean so when the autocomplete method is called is has the state the user selected on the page to populate a list of suburbs.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `<f:parameter` tab inside the `rich:suggestionbox`. My task was filtering a list according to some attribute of the list element, where sometimes that attribute could be ignored. Like, sometimes I want a list of only citrus fruit, and sometimes I want the entire list of available fruit.

In the page:

```
<rich:suggestionbox usingSuggestObjects="true"
        suggestionAction="#{listBuilder.autocompleteFilterFruit('')}" var="ind"
        for="fruitInput" fetchValue="#{fruit.name}" id="suggestion" >
    <f:param name="constrainInd" value="#{basket.isConstrainedToCitrus}" />

    ...

</rich:suggestionbox>
```

I had one class (`Basket`) that knew if the list had to be special-filtered, and another class (`ListBuilder`) that built the list.

In `Basket`:

```
public Boolean getIsConstrainedToCitrus ()
{
    return new Boolean ( logic that answers "is this basket for citrus only" );
}
```

In ListBuilder:

```
public List<Fruit> autocompleteFilterFruit (Object arg)
{
    List<Fruit> rtnList = new ArrayList<Fruit> ();

    String suggestion = (String) arg;

    // get the filter control that the page retrieved from the Basket
    //
    Map<String,String> params = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext ().getRequestParameterMap();
    boolean isConstrainedToCitrus = "true".equals (params.get ("constrainInd"));

    // allFruit is a pre-initialized list of all the available fruit. use it to populate the return list according 
    // to the filter rules and matches to the auto-complete suggestions
    for (Fruit item : allFruit)
    {
        if ((!isConstrainedToCitrus || item.isCitrus())  &&  item.name.startsWith(suggestion))
        {
            rtnList.add (item);
        }
    }
    return rtnList;
}
```